# Inserting date()->format(Y-m-d): "Call to a member function modify() on a non-object."

Tags: php

I have this code and every time I run it, it returns the same php error:

> Fatal Error: Call to a member function modify() on a non-object.

Below is the code that generates the error.

```
$datetime_beginning = new DateTime('60 days ago');

do {
 $insert_days= mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tocreate (date_full) VALUES ('".$datetime_beginning->format('Y-m-d')."');") or die(mysql_error());

 $datetime_bigining->modify('+1 day');

}while($datetime_bigining!=$final_time);
```

`$final_time` is define elsewhere in the full code.

Comment: Given that there is no error on `$datetime_beginning->format(...)`, I think this is a basic typo issue.

Comment: `datetime_bigining` vs `datetime_beginning` - case closed

Comment: and you need stack overflow for this? come'on you people learn some debugging ???

Comment: Same error changing the spelling

Comment: @RodolfoPuig Edit your post to reflect your new code and error, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. **$datetime_beginning** vs **$datetime_bigining**

Try this:

```
$datetime_beginning = new DateTime('60 days ago');

do {
 $insert_days= mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tocreate (date_full) VALUES ('".$datetime_beginning->format('Y-m-d')."');") or die(mysql_error());

 $datetime_beginning->modify('+1 day');

}while($datetime_beginning!=$final_time);
```

Comment: You really kept the same typo as in the original post...?

Comment: you have the same typo issue..

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too quick. Editted.

Comment: Thank you guys. It all worked fine now